# Implementing a finite state machine with a single coroutine

Tags: coroutine, fsm, state-machine

I'm looking at ways to implement an FSM, which led to my first encounter with coroutines.

I saw several examples ([here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/08/29/co-routines-as-an-alternative-to-state-machines/), [here](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/Coroutines.pdf) and [here](http://www.crystalclearsoftware.com/soc/coroutine/coroutine/finite_state_machines.html)) which hint that a state machine can be implemented by a single coroutine. However, what I noticed all these machines have in common is that, excluding cycles, they are trees - that is, there is a single path (excluding cycles) from the start node to every other node - and that maps nicely to the hierarchical control flow provided by nested `if`s. The state machine I'm trying to model has at least one state with more than one path from the start node to it (if cycles are eliminated, it's a directed acyclic graph). and I can't imagine what kind of control flow (apart from `goto`s) can achieve that, or if it's possible at all.

Alternatively, I may use a separate coroutine to handle each state and yield to some sort of dispatcher coroutine. However, I don't see any particular benefit of using coroutines over regular functions in this setup.

Here's a simple state machine that I have trouble modelling:

```
A --'a'--> B
A --'b'--> C
B --'a'--> C
B --'b'--> A
C --'a'--> A
C --'b'--> B
```

And here is what I have so far. The final implementation will be in C++ using Boost, but I'm using Python for prototyping.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

def StateMachine():
    while True:
        print("  Entered state A")
        input = (yield)
        if input == "a":
            print("  Entered state B")
            input = (yield)
            if input == "a":
                # How to enter state C from here?
                pass
            elif input == "b":
                continue
        elif input == "b":
            print("  Entered state C")
            input = (yield)
            if input == "b":
                continue
            elif input == "a":
                # How to enter state B from here?
                pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sm = StateMachine()
    sm.__next__()
    while True:
        for line in input():
        sm.send(line)
```

Can this coroutine be fixed to correctly model the state machine? Or do I have to go some other way about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would model the state machine explicitly:

```
def StateMachine():
    state = 'A'
    while True:
        print(state)
        input = (yield)
        if state == 'A':
            if input == 'a':
                state = 'B'
            elif input == 'b':
                state = 'C'
            else:
                break
        elif state == 'B':
            if input == 'a':
                state = 'C'
            elif input == 'b':
                state = 'A'
            else:
                break
        elif state == 'C':
            if input == 'a':
                state = 'A'
            elif input == 'b':
                state = 'B'
            else:
                break
        else:
            break
```

This should translate very neatly to C++ using nested `switch` statements or a state transition table.

If you prefer an implicit model, you need a way to handle the cycles in your state machine. In C or C++, this would probably end up being `goto`. I wouldn't recommend this approach, but if you're more comfortable with it than explicit state, here's what it might look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define start(state) switch(state) { case 0:;
#define finish default:;}
#define yield(state, value) do { state = __LINE__; return (value); case __LINE__:; } while(0)

struct coroutine {
    int state;
};

int
run(struct coroutine *c, char input)
{
    start(c->state)
    {
A:
        printf("Entered state A\n");
        yield(c->state, 1);
        if(input == 'a') goto B;
        if(input == 'b') goto C;
B:
        printf("Entered state B\n");
        yield(c->state, 1);
        if(input == 'a') goto C;
        if(input == 'b') goto A;
C:
        printf("Entered state C\n");
        yield(c->state, 1);
        if(input == 'a') goto A;
        if(input == 'b') goto B;
    } finish;

    return 0;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int a;
    struct coroutine c = {0};

    while((a = getchar()) != EOF && run(&c, a));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Having explicit states is always an option, but is something I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I think the problem you're going to have is that your trying to represent a cyclic graph as a tree. That's only going to be possible if you allow a way to re-enter the tree; that's going to take either something like a `goto` into the middle of the tree or a variable to save the state so that the tree can be re-entered at the top.

Comment: I believe so myself, but I can't find a reference to "coroutines alone can't be used to implement a cyclic finite state machine".

Comment: It's not really specific to coroutines. You want to implement each state transition as its own if branch, but you need to jump across branches of the tree. Python doesn't have `goto`, but C and C++ do, I'll edit my answer to include an example in C with `goto`s. I don't think it's the best approach, but it does demonstrate what's possible.

Comment: After coding it, it does look cleaner than I expected (I started with a hybrid of if branch logic, like you had in Python, but switched to just `goto`, which cleaned things up substantially). It should probably handle inputs other than just 'a' and 'b' (maybe by just returning 0). The `#define`s at the top are a little icky, but allow you to implement generators in standard C, with a little syntactic sugar. Python is basically doing the same thing behind the scenes with its `yield` keyword.

Comment: An additional side note that I wanted to avoid mentioning for fear of muddying the waters is this: coroutines or generators themselves are often implemented behind the scenes as state machines (where the state is the line or instruction to execute on the next resume). I feel I have to at least point this out, since there really isn't any "behind the scenes" in C. That's what those `#define` macros are really all about.

Comment: Thank you for your time. We ended up using Boost meta-state machine since we had old code that could be modified, but I got my answer: coroutines as control flow alone, in general, are **not** sufficient to implement a finite state machine.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, every finite state machine can be implemented with a single coroutine with just one of the following structures:

- tests on auxiliary variables
- `goto` statements
- multi-level exits from loops

Of course, `if-then-else` and `while` structures are considered available. On the other hand, such an implementation is not always feasible with only single-level exits.

Thus, the specific example is written, without state variables and `goto`' s, as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 
# Python doesn't support multilevel exits, so try/except can be used instead.
# However, for this FSM, single-level exits are sufficient.  
def StateMachine():
  while True:
    while True:
      print("  Entered state A")
      input = (yield)
      if input == "a":
          print("  Entered state B")
          input = (yield)
          if input == "a": 
            break
          elif input == "b": 
            pass
      elif input == "b": 
            break    
    while True:
      print("  Entered state C")
      input = (yield)
      if input == "a": 
          break
      elif input == "b": 
          print("  Entered state B")
          input = (yield)
          if input == "a": 
            pass
          elif input == "b": 
            break
if __name__=="__main__":
     sm = StateMachine()
     sm.__next__()
     while True:
       for line in input():
        sm.send(line)
```